# React Joyride scrolling

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my application window is fixed height and there are many small panels with custom scrolling.
For elements that are hidden can I make joyride scroll to the element according to the relative panel and scroll it if its not visisble?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you find any solution to this? 

Apparently, joyride always consider documents scroll and not the individual component.

Comment: Not yet as of now I skipped this and changed my tour setup. With custom scrolls i'm still not able to find the solution

Comment: You should open an issue on the github repo, or add to an existing one.

Answer (score -1):

you can use the `props scrollToSteps={true}` in ReactJoyride component